# Powershell and service fabric - how to select specific information and use it later actions?

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

Below is code how I connect to my service fabric cluster and take needed application health information:

```
$ConnectArgs = @{
 ConnectionEndpoint = "mycluster:19000";  
 X509Credential = $True;  
 StoreLocation = 'CurrentUser';  
 StoreName = "MY"; 
 FindType = 'FindByThumbprint';  
 FindValue = "My_thumbprint"
 }
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ConnectArgs 
Get-ServiceFabricApplicationHealth -ApplicationName fabric:/Myapp -ExcludeHealthStatistics
```

But currently there are lot of information, what I do not need. How to select just specific information from results? I need just ServiceHealthState information. I was able to exclude some information from application health, but didnt manage to exclude more.

UPDATE:

I found the following solution, which is close to what I try to achieve:

```
$health = Get-ServiceFabricApplicationHealth -ApplicationName "fabric:/Myapp" 
If ($health.AggregatedHealthState -eq "OK") {
    Write-Host "$($clusterApplication)'s health is ok!"
} Else {
    Write-Error "$($clusterApplication)'s health is not ok"
}
```

But I do not need to monitor AggregatedHealthState, because I am only interested in one part, which is under ServiceHealthStates, see example:

> ApplicationName: fabric:/Myapp
>   AggregatedHealthState: Error
>   ServiceHealthStates:
>
> > ServiceName: fabric:/Myapp/Frontend
> >     AggregatedHealthState: Error
> >     ServiceName: fabric:/Myapp/Backend
> >     **AggregatedHealthState : Ok**

But I dont know how to select this part, didnt find this from Google as well, hopefully someone could help.

Comment: `select-object propertyname`?

Comment: You might want to remove *how to use this ServiceHealthState information to perform node restart* from this question so it doesn't get closed as too broad.

Comment: That is actually good idea, did this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution what suits to me, post it here as well, if anyone else is facing against same question, my solution:

```
# Connect to Service Fabric cluster
$ConnectArgs = @{
 ConnectionEndpoint = "mycluster:19000";  
 X509Credential = $True;  
 StoreLocation = 'CurrentUser';  
 StoreName = "MY"; 
 FindType = 'FindByThumbprint';  
 FindValue = "My_Thumbprint"
 }
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ConnectArgs 

# Test Cluster connection
$Connection=Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection
If ($Connection -eq "True") { 
    Write-Host "OK"}
Else 
{
    Write-Host "Connection to Service fabric cluster failed" 
}

# Service Fabric application health monotoring
$AppName="MyApp"

$AppHealth=Get-ServiceFabricApplicationHealth -ApplicationName $AppName 
$AppHealthBE=$AppHealth.ServiceHealthStates -match "Backend"

$node=Get-ServiceFabricApplicationHealth -ApplicationName $AppName
$nodetorestart=$node.DeployedApplicationHealthStates.NodeName -match  "MyNode"

If ($AppHealthBE.AggregatedHealthState -eq "Ok") {
   Write-Host "$($clusterApplication)/backend is OK"
   }
   Else
   {
   Write-Host "Need to perform restart on node: $nodetorestart)"
   #Restart-ServiceFabricNode -NodeName $nodetorestart
   }
```